# Separate a compact and a closed subset in $\mathbb{R}^n$

Tags: real-analysis, general-topology, functional-analysis, analysis

Let $K\subset \mathbb{R}^n$ a compact subset. And $F\subset \mathbb{R}^n$ a closed subset such that
$$ K \cap F = \emptyset.$$
How can we deduce that there is $a>0$ such that
$$\| y-x\|>a,$$
for all $x\in K$ and $y\in F$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Hint**

Suppose such $a$ doesn't exist, i.e. for all $n\in \mathbb N$, there is $x_n\in K$ and $y_n\in F$ s.t. $$\|x_n-y_n\|\leq \frac{1}{n}.$$

1. Prove that $(x_n)$ is bounded.
2. Prove that $(x_n)$ and $(y_n)$ are convergent (up to a subsequence) and has the same limit.
3. Find a contradiction.

Answer (score 1):

Assume there exists no such $a$, and use compactness of $K$ to find a solution.

*Hint*: $K$ is a compact subset of $\mathbb{R}^n$, so every sequence of points in $K$ has a converging subsequence. :) You can use this to find a contradiction.

Answer (score 0):

On $K$, the function $x \to d(x,A)$ is continuous and real-valued (values in $(0,+\infty)$. It assumes a minimum by compacntess of $K$. QED.